# HttpReponseMessage responseText not showing in CORS request to a Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have set up a WebApi project which is hosted in a different server.
I am trying to call a web api POST method from my web project.
The request is a CORS.
I able to call the method successfully from the web project and the debugger shows everything working fine.
All the methods send an error/success response from the api to the client calling by initializing the HttpResponseMessage object.

Example:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Submitted successfully." );
```

Ideally at the client end the message

> "Submitted successfully."

should appear in the "responseText" property of the response object but for this CORS request its coming up empty.
I am getting HttpStatusCode.OK code correctly as 200 but missing the response text as I need to inform the user whether the event happened correctly or not.

On the contrary, If I call the api methods from the same domain I do get the things working fine and the error message in the "responseText" property of the response object.

I've been hunting down the issue and not able to get any hints what is the actual problem.

In the API

```
  [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage SendResponse()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Submitted successfully.");
            return response;
        }
```

From From Client

```
        $.post("http://127.0.0.1:81/api/Controler/SendResponse", function (data) {
            if (data) {
                alert(data);
            } else {
            }
        });
```

Please do help and suggest what could be the reason.
Much help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the code where you do the request.

Comment: Hi, have you looked at this article http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api?

Comment: @CodeCaster I have added sample code.

Comment: Well your `function(data)` is the success handler. If it doesn't get called, the `$.post()` call wasn't succesful. Check your browser's console. It's not like "with CORS your response body gets stripped".

Comment: Yes @CodeCaster , this is success handler and also it is getting called. What I am getting is data.responseText as empty, instead that should contain "Submitted successfully."

I get data.responseText = "Submitted successfully." when in same domain.